# Modify the behavior of jquery tag-it based on autocomplete library to use ajax JSON sources

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tags, jquery-ui-autocomplete, tag-it

I'm trying to add some functionality to jQuery plugin [tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) based on auto-complete :

a) I try to filtering my JSON data to display only name of tag.

A JSON sample returned by `/repo/json` :

```
[{id:1, name:"0.8-alpha-1", category:"version"}, {id:2, name:"0.8-alpha-2", category:"version"}, {id:3, name:"0.8-alpha-3", category:"version"}, {id:4, name:"0.8-alpha-4", category:"version"}, {id:5, name:"0.8-alpha-1", category:"version"}, {id:6, name:"0.8-alpha-2", category:"version"}, {id:7, name:"0.8-alpha-3", category:"version"}, {id:8, name:"0.8-alpha-4", category:"version"}]
```

b) I want to submit the id of the tag when user submits data, and not the name.

c) I try to add some constraint to my tag-it input field : user cannot validate a tag which is not in the JSON returned by my `/repo/json call`.

I don't want to fork tag-it repository, and it seems possible to to test intersection between user array and search with `beforeTagAdded` option.

I try without success at this time, because I don't know where I can find the list of tags to realize intersection.

My js code :

```
 $(function(){
    $("#singleFieldTags").tagit({
      tagSource: function(search, showChoices) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/repo/json",
          dataType:   "json",
          data: {q: search.term},
          success: function(choices) {
            showChoices(choices);
          }
        })},
           beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
           //if ($.inArray(ui.tagLabel, search) == -1) {
           //   $("#singleFieldTags").tagit("removeTagByLabel", ui.tagLabel);
           // }
            console.log(ui.tag);
           }});

    });
```

The html form :

```
<form name="data" action="/repo/uploadMole" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="tags" id="singleFieldTags" ><br/>
    <input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Forking the repository might be your best bet here.

Comment: Hum no answer, perhaps it's too complicated, i need to up the bounties ?

Comment: Is forking the repository and implementing the functionality a satisfactory answer? If so I'll take a stab at it.

Comment: `tagSource` is [deprecated](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/js/tag-it.js#L101). You should use `autocomplete.source`

Comment: Why do you want to use tag-it. If your requirements are different then try building it urself.

Comment: @gaurav Simple answer, i cannot build such a project myself because i have no time to learn correctly jquery in order to make this. I use tag-it for that in a first intention, to simplify my work, but user comments prove that is probably not adapted for my specifications. I search alternative now with other libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask you want to **submit**, something different. Then lets take that single point of entry:

```
$('#data').submit(function() {
    // Change the value we are submitting
    var tagids = [];
    $.each($('#singleFieldTags').val().split(','),
           function(idx, taglabel){
               tagids.push(lookup_tagid_for_label(taglabel));
           }
    )
    $('#singleFieldTags').val(tagids.join(','));          
    return true; // Let the event go on.
});
```

That should change the labels with the ids before submit.

`lookup_tagid_for_label`, could either do the ajax call again, but it may be cheaper to cache it on the field at first lookup:

```
$("#singleFieldTags").tagit({
     autocomplete: {
        source: function(search, showChoices) {
                    $.getJSON("/repo/json", {q: search.term},
                        function (data) {
                            var choices = [];
                            $.each(data, function (idx, tag) {
                                choices.push(tag.name);
                                $("#singleFieldTags").data(tag.name, tag.id);
                            });
                            showChoices(choices);
                    });
                }
});
```

Then you can replace `lookup_tagid_for_label(taglabel)` with `$("#singleFieldTags").data(taglabel)`.

In contrary to my other answer, that expected tag-it to follow the autocomplete-api, this [works now](http://jsfiddle.net/AnGDJ/5/).

Comment: Yes, works great, json and id push !
I hope your answer can help other people which use tag-it :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the tags when they are added breaks [removal](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/js/tag-it.js#L501) and possibly other things as well. You could try the mitigate that by writing a `beforeTagRemoved` handler and possibly other handlers in the future. (a pain to maintain).

As I commented you should use the [autocomplete api](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it#autocomplete-object). The doc points further to [jquery-ui](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source). The data can be in this form:

> ... An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

So I suspect this could be enough:

```
 $("#singleFieldTags").tagit({
     autocomplete: {
        source: function(search, showChoices) {
                    $.getJSON("/repo/json", {q: search.term},
                              function(data) {
                                  var choices = [];
                                  $.each(data, function(idx, tag){
                                      choices.push({label: tag.name,
                                                    value: tag.id})
                                      });
                                  showChoices(choices);
                              });
                }
         }
     })
```

**Sadly this doesn't work as expected as tag-it, currently [drops the label](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/63f7c1189b223a0edcba407aee7420e975824a97/js/tag-it.js#L283) and uses just the id, when creating the tag.** I think tag-it should be cleaned up and support the complete autocomplete api.

#### Update

[The maintainer agrees](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/pull/113#issuecomment-15783550) with this. So this answer may become the canonical answer in the future.

Comment: Thanks for this start of answer, do you have an idea or some path for json parsing before displaying name of tag ?

Comment: @reyman64: reading up on the api to find the shortest way for your json parsing, I came up with this.

Comment: Ok, i try to make a jsfiddle with your answer later, and i update the post. Thanks for help, i give you the bounty ;)

Comment: @reyman64 if this version doesn't work, you can always combine the $.getJSON with the first version approach. Be sure to edit it for posterity :)

Comment: @reyman64: You've messed up the ajax call, it sort of does work: http://jsfiddle.net/AnGDJ/4/ I've used `$.post` instead of `$.getJSON` , because [braindead jsfiddle's `echo` echo's POST data](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html). Why their HTTP echo expects POST and not GET is beyond me, as the echo service should be both *safe* and *idempotent*.

Comment: Hum ok, thanks a lot, with this working example, i try later to push id in hidden input field to submit, and display the tag name in tag input field. Probably need a function to rebuild input hidden field which contain id at each add/remove of tags.

Comment: I say sort of, because [tag-it uses just the value and drops the label](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/63f7c1189b223a0edcba407aee7420e975824a97/js/tag-it.js#L283) to make the tag. So you end up with the id in the label of the tag. So you either change tag-it, so this clean API call works. Or you try the route, from before my edit...