# use an external Json as source with tagit.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete

I have some problem with the tagit.js script (https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it)
i know this kind of questions has been asked before : 
[Modify the behavior of jquery tag-it based on autocomplete library to use ajax JSON sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242354/modify-the-behavior-of-jquery-tag-it-based-on-autocomplete-library-to-use-ajax-j)
OR 
[jQuery TagIt (autocomplete) Fetching JSON list via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101231/jquery-tagit-autocomplete-fetching-json-list-via-ajax)

In my case, i can load tags from an external json, but there is no intelligent autocompletion. When i type "Hello", the plug in show me the whole tag which are on my Json, with no logical order.

My code :

```
  $(function(){

       $('#biginput').tagit({

            allowSpaces:true,

            autocomplete: {delay: 0, minLength: 0},
            afterTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
                launchsearch();
                console.log(ui.tag);
            },
            afterTagRemoved: function(event, ui) {
                launchsearch();
                console.log(ui.tag);
            },



             tagSource: function(search, showChoices) {
                var that = this;
                $.ajax({
                  url: "search.json",
                  data: search,
                  success: function(choices) {
                    showChoices(that._subtractArray(choices, that.assignedTags()));
                  }
                });
              }


        });

});
```

I have tried to reproduce my problem in jsfiddle, but it doesn't work... 
Look here : http://jsfiddle.net/bsofcn41/
My goal is just to have tag autocompletion with a json file as basis.

it seems that this script is very badly updated and maintained in github. Maybe there is better script of this kind ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [jquery-tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/). It uses json as autocomplete data.